# Existe diferença de performance entre ng-bind e {{ }} (interpolation)?

Tags: angularjs

Eu percebi que no Angular temos as duas formas de se exibir os valores no DOM.

Uma é usando o as chaves `{{}}`, e outras, é usando o atributo `ng-bind`.

Exemplo com chaves:

```
<div ng-repeat="moderador in ['bigown', 'rray']">
  {{ moderador }}
</div>
```

Exemplo com `ng-bind`:

```
<div ng-repeat="moderador in ['bigown', 'rray']" ng-bind="moderador">
</div>
```

Ambas as formas acima imprimirão os valores no `Dom`.

Mas em relação à essas duas formas, pergunto:

- Usar `ng-bind`, por ser um atributo, pode ser mais performático do que usar chaves?
- Quais são os pontos a favor e os contra de se usar um ou outro?

Comment: Por gentileza, quem deu o negativo, poderia apresentar o problema na pergunta? Assim, eu poderia melhorar o conteúdo dela, ajudando quem tenha dúvidas a estar qualificado em saná-las

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conforme esta resposta no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23382400/1518921), sim, existe diferença, não sei se é significante no resultado final ou se é perceptível, mas usar os "brackets" (`{{}}`) é sim mais lento.

O `ng-bind` é uma diretiva e coloca um "observador" sobre a variável que foi passada, assim o `ng-bind` só será aplicável quando o valor passado é realmente mudar.

Os "brackets" `{{}}`, por outro lado vão verificar e atualizar em todos os `$.digest()`, mesmo que isso não seja necessário.